# Is it possible to set expiry time of a dynamic QR code in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, qr-code

I am generating a dynamic QR code in Angular 8 application using **[angularx-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-qrcode)** library. After scanning the QR, user will be navigated to a third party app.

The QR code should be expired at same day after 2 hours or user will not be able to scan the QR code next time once scanned. Is it possible to implement it in any way?

Comment: The user will *always* be able to scan it. At most, you can only have some kind of private URL shortener that refuse to resolve expired shortened URLs, but it won't help if someone retrieves the redirected address unless you also expire the target address.

Comment: After scanning the QR code, user will be navigated to a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with an observable. Do this in your .ts file:

```
   showQR$ = interval(10_000)
      .pipe(
        switchMap((cnt) => (cnt === 1 ? of(false) : of(true))),
        take(2)
      );
```

and in the template like this:

```
<ng-container *nfIf="showQR$ | async">
 qr componente
</ng-container>
```